# Same image instance multiple times in canvas does not work, right? Alternatives?

Tags: wpf, image

Given that the `Canvas.SetTop()` etc. static functions take the reference of a content object as argument (in contrast to the item index, returned by `var i = mycanvas.Children.Add(...)`), I cannot see how I could possibly add the same instance of an image at various locations. (Think the 8 pawns on a chess board, for example). It kind of feels like a waste to create N identical images for that use case. In case of a GO board, I would actually have to create 361 white and black stone images?

In immediate mode graphical models it would be something like N bitblit operations from the same source to the target locations.

Now the question is, what is the idiomatic way to do this in WPF? Efficiently, not just somehow...

Does it make sense to load the same Bitmap once and then set it as source to multiple Image instances?

Right now, I contemplate to render just 1 image for the whole picture and add that to the canvas, if there is no better way to do it anyway.

Comment: "Does it make sense to load the same Bitmap once and then set it as source to multiple Image instances?" You've got it.

Comment: @Clemens I was not sure if the image copies the bitmap and possibly tries to apply a layout run to it...

Comment: @Clemens Having played with that approach for a while.. I am confused: Working set for that tiny GUI, rendering a chessboard: 21MB (release, anycpu) and if I make app bigger and smaller with mouse quickly, working set rises to 31MB while never resizing the canvas and its content...only the main window. Does not look like an efficient approach to me. Or is that "normal" for wpf? What do those extra 10MB do while resizing the window?

Comment: Use a memory profiler to find out what your app is doing.